# Insert document name & document path in vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, file-upload

I have file upload and upload link button and submit button .. so when i select file and click on upload then file name display in label and when i again click on browse file and select file and click on upload then file name again save in label so means multiple file name display in label i.e.

```
abc.docx
def.docx
```

.. and so on ..

now i try to save these files in database with different record means if these files save in database table then look like this

```
ID DocumentName DocumentPath
1   abc.docx    /downloads/abc.docx
2   def.docx   /files/def.docx
```

for this i try this 
sp

```
        alter procedure spupload_file
    @DocumentName varchar(100),
    @Doctype tinyint
    as


    insert into DocDownloads (DocumentID,DocumentName,DocType)

    select (select max(DocumentID) from DocDownloads )+ROW_NUMBER()  over(order by @DocumentName),@DocumentName,7
```

code

```
      Protected Sub LinkButton1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles LinkButton1.Click
        uploadmultiple_file(fileUpEx.FileName)
    End Sub

    Public Sub uploadmultiple_file(filename As String)
        If fileUpEx.HasFiles Then
            For Each uploadedfile As HttpPostedFile In fileUpEx.PostedFiles
                'Label4.Text = ("<b>File: </b>" + uploadedfile.FileName)
                Label4.Text += String.Format("{0}<br />", uploadedfile.FileName)
            Next
        End If
    End Sub


 Protected Sub pb_Add_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles pb_submit.Click
  Dim strKeyName() As String = {"DocumentName", "DocType"}
        Dim objKeyVal() As Object = {Label4.Text,7}
        structDb = objDataSet.ExecSP("tbl", "spupload_file", strKeyName, objKeyVal)
        If structDb.intCode = 0 Then
            Label5.Text = structDb.strMessage
            Label5.CssClass = "error"
            Exit Sub
        End If


    End Sub
```

when i try this ... this shows record in database table like

```
1 abc.docx<br />def.docx<br />
```

where as i want like this

```
1 abc.docx
2 def.docx
```

Index was outside the bounds of the array.

and how i insert also document path

any help ?

**UPDATED**

ok according to @Andy Reid
i try this

```
 For Each file As HttpPostedFile In ListBox1.Items
        Dim DocumentName As String = file.FileName

        Dim strKeyName() As String = {"DocumentName", "DocType"}
        Dim objKeyVal() As Object = {DocumentName, 7}
 structDb = objDataSet.ExecSP("tbl", "spupload_file", strKeyName, objKeyVal)

    Next


    If structDb.intCode = 0 Then
        Label5.Text = structDb.strMessage
        Label5.CssClass = "error"
        Exit Sub
    End If
```

but this shows error

**An exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in DecibelCRM.dll but was not handled in user code
Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem' to type 'System.Web.HttpPostedFile'.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a listbox instead of the Label4, if dataset DocumentID is AutoIncrement

```
 Protected Sub UploadLinkButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles UploadLinkButton.Click
    uploadmultiple_file(FileUpEx.FileName)

End Sub

Public Sub uploadmultiple_file(filename As String)
    If fileUpEx.HasFiles Then
        'Add each PostedFile to list Box instead of using label
        For Each uploadedfile As HttpPostedFile In fileUpEx.PostedFiles
            FilesListBox.Items.Add(uploadedfile.FileName)
        Next

    End If

End Sub

Protected Sub pb_Add_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles SubmitButton.Click
    Dim objDataSet As New objDataSet 'Or whatever you have
    Dim DocType as Integer = 7

    'Gets each file from FilesListBox to insert them into objDataSet        
    For Each file As HttpPostedFile In FilesListBox.Items
        Dim DocumentName as String = file.FileName

        'Because the DocumentID is AutoIncrement, you don't need to enter it here
        objDataSet.DocDownloads.AddDocDownloadsRow(DocumentName, DocType)

    Next

End Sub
```

This will be for the data table, it should put each PostedFile as a new Row into DocDownloads. Upon doing some more research, the full path isn't accessible due to security reasons

Comment: i try you solution and try to do with SP but this shows error.. please check updated code in my question ..

Comment: What does the code look like for 'objDataSet.ExecSP()'?

In my answer where I put: 'objDataSet.DocDownloads.AddDocDownloadsRow(DocumentName, DocType)'... this should be doing what you want 'spupload_file' to do isn't it?      It basically inserts a new row into the DocDownloads table in objDataSet using the DocumentName and DocType.

Answer (score 0):

Your code:

```
 Public Sub uploadmultiple_file(filename As String)
        If fileUpEx.HasFiles Then
            For Each uploadedfile As HttpPostedFile In fileUpEx.PostedFiles
                'Label4.Text = ("<b>File: </b>" + uploadedfile.FileName)
                Label4.Text += String.Format("{0}<br />", uploadedfile.FileName)
            Next
        End If
    End Sub
```

Try

```
Public Sub uploadmultiple_file(filename As String)

  If fileUpEx.HasFiles Then
    Try
       For Each uploadedfile As HttpPostedFile In fileUpEx.PostedFiles                       
           Label4.Text += uploadedfile.FileName & vbCRLF
           'Possibly something like: "Label4.Text += uploadedfile.FullPath & vbCRLF" for the document path
       Next

    Catch ex as Exception
      'Whatever exception handling code    
    End try

   End If

 End Sub
```

Comment: this is for path? and what about for data in table?